# Как преобразовать тип bool в enum?

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Есть перечисление:

```
enum {
 FALSE=0,
 TRUE=1
}BOOL;
```

Нужно, чтобы присваивание вида BOOL var=true; было законным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю для чего это может понадобится, однако:

```
enum BOOL : bool {
    FALSE = false,
    TRUE = true
};

int main() {
    BOOL var = static_cast<BOOL>(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Да обычное приведение, можно даже не указывать базовый тип:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

enum BOOL
{
    FALSE=0,
    TRUE=1
};

int main()
{
    BOOL var = BOOL(true);
    BOOL war = static_cast<BOOL>(true);
}
```

https://ideone.com/uL9JqG